# Cannot access visitor's ip address in php

Tags: php, logging, ip-address

i am trying to store ip addresses of people who are visiting my web site. For that i use the below given code.

```
$serverIP=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

but instead of getting an IP like `112.200.xxx.xxx` (when i visit), i got `192.9.200.195`..

somebody please help me

thanks in advance

tismon

Comment: What's wrong with 192.9.200.195?

Comment: What's the problem with `192.9.200.195`? Is it not your IP? You can check your external IP with e.g. http://www.whatismyip.com/

Comment: 192.9.200.195 is a valid IP. In fact, geolocation tells me it belongs to Sun Microsystems in Santa Clara, CA. It's the 192.168.x.x range that's private.

Comment: 192.9.200.195 is my local ip. when i visit whatismyip.com, it shows something starting with 112.200.XXX.XXX. that is my problem..

Comment: @ NullUserException my golocation is in india..

Answer (score 3):

try this, maybe its a proxy(?)

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
{
  $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
else
{
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
} 
echo $ip;
```

Answer (score 2):

looks like you're thinking `192.9.200.195` is a local ip-adress - but its not, local adresses you mean are starting with `192.168.`. `192.9.200.195` looks ok to me, if it's not, please try to explain you problem more detailed.

Comment: yep, i think 192.9.200.195 is my local ip. when i visit whatismyip.com, it shows a diff ip starting with 112.200. should i change anything in php.ini ?

Comment: @tismon: as said, it's not your local ip (or: this shouldn't be your local ip as that would mean you network is set up totaly wrong) - maybe the 112.200... is saved in one of the other variables posted by yogesh (but i don't think so). do you use any of this "i wanna be annonymous in the internet, so hide my ip"-programs?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
echo getRealIpAddr();
```

Comment: that is also showing the same ip starting with 192.9. when i visit whatismyip.com, it shows a diff ip starting with 112.200.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
<?php
$var = file_get_contents('http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp');
print $var;
?>
```